# reactjs i18n change translation on demand

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

I use i18n (`react-i18next`) in my react js application. Translation with language chooser etc works absolutly fine.

But now I want to change some texts programmatically on demand.

I tried this:

```
i18n.t('clinical:sde.export.studyTitle', {lng: "en"})
```

and

```
i18n.t('clinical:sde.export.studyTitle', {"en"})
```

It always returns the german string from current setting and not the "on demand" english text. Is there a solution to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work, you need to check that the dynamic language is loaded (this what `i18n.changeLanguage` does).

I've made a simple test, and it works.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-i18next-example-forked-ueng1?file=/src/app.js

Comment: The change language function it selves works fine but then the whole UI is changed. I only want to change this single translation snippet and not whole ui

Comment: Check the example that I've made, it changes only the specific text language, not the entire language.
See that the title remains in english

Comment: it was a kind of stupidness ... in my english translation file was an mistake in the json ... so it always fallback to german ... sorry for that.